# R: String Operations on Large Data Set (How to speed up?)

Tags: r, bigdata

I have a large data.frame (>4M rows) in which one column contains character strings. I want to perform several string operations/match regular expressions on each text field (e.g. `gsub`).

I'm wondering how I can speed up operations? Basically, I'm performing a bunch of

```
gsub(patternvector," [token] ",tweetDF$textcolumn)
gsub(patternvector," [token] ",tweetDF$textcolumn)
....
```

I'm running R on a 8GB RAM Mac and tried to move it to the cloud (Amazon EC2 large instance with ~64GB RAM), but it's not going very fast.

I've heard of the several packages (`bigmemory`, `ff`) and found an overview about High Performance/Parallel Computing for R [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html).

Does anyone have recommendations for a package most suitable for speeding up string operations? Or knows of a source explaining how apply the standard R string functions (`gsub`,..) to the 'objects' created by these 'High Performance Computing packages' ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mclapply` or any other function that allows for parallel processing should speed up the task significantly. If you are not using parallel processing you are only using only 1 CPU, no matter how many CPUs your computer has available.